# Help deciphering rafter span table from International Residential Code

Tags: engineering

I want to have a better understanding of how to read the IRC rafter span table - Here's an [article](https://buildingcodetrainer.com/how-to-size-roof-rafters/) which shows a couple of tables which I am including here.

[image: Roof Live Load]

[image: Ground Snow load]

Now let's say I have a 12:12 roof - Using calculation I would derive a Roof Live Load. However only R802.4.1(2) lists Roof Live Load and only for 20psf. The other tables only show Ground Snow Load without taking into account roof pitch. I have the actual IRC 2018 and sure enough there is like 2 tables for Roof Live Load and only to 20psf.

Question - If my roof live load is say 40. How would I use these tables? and why are so many of the tables listing only GSL - flat roof only?

Comment: Go to the source, not the article - perhaps the article picked those for the example it was explaining.

Comment: @SolarMike Nah  - as I mentioned I have the actual IRC and its just like that. Roof load for 10-20 then anything beyond that the tables are for ground snow load. There are no tables I can find for say 40 psf roof load.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate rafter capacities for free at the link below. This is what structural engineers use to design rafters.

To play it safe I wouldn't exceed a spacing of 16" OC.

https://www.forteweb.com

Comment: Structural engineers use the National Design Specification (NDS) to compute rafter sizes. The publisher of the NDS has a rafter calculator at https://awc.org/calculators/span-options-calculator-for-wood-joists-and-rafters/ that I would rank ahead of any other rafter calculator. The publisher of the NDS also publishes rafter span tables that are available for free at https://awc.org/codes-and-standards/span-tables/.

Answer (score 0):

Standard roof live load is 20 psf. That's applied to the roof's horizontal projection just like snow. There's no correction based on roof pitch in the IRC, so you shouldn't be calculating anything for live load. There is a correction in ASCE 7 (the source of the IRC's 20 psf live load), where the roof live load ranges from 12 psf to 20 psf with lower live load for steeper roofs. The live load is calibrated for roof construction when there's piles of roofing material up there. I guess less material gets piled up on steeper roofs. Regardless, if you're operating under the IRC, then your roof live load is 20 psf.

A 40 psf live load is outside the scope of the IRC tables, where you would need to hire an architect or engineer to get specs to satisfy a building official. If you're not doing something goofy up there (like a deck), then you don't need 40 psf tables. Technically it would be theoretically sound to use deck joist span tables from the IRC's R507 to get rafters sized for 40 psf live load, but you're not going to get a building official to join you for that adventure.

The ground snow load also requires no adjustment for pitch. This is intuitive in that the snow falls uniformly, with a highly pitched roof receiving no more snow than a flat roof.